# How to test and deploy a project using docker-compose and circleci?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, circleci, circleci-2.0

I've the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/nginx
    depends_on:
     - php
    volumes:
     - ./config/docker/nginx/app_vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./public/:/srv/public/:ro
      - ./var/:/srv/var/:rw

  php:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/php
    depends_on:
     - mysql
      - redis
    working_dir: /srv
    volumes:
     - ./config/docker/php/app.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro

  mysql:
    image: mysql

  node:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/node
    working_dir: /srv
    volumes:
     - ./:/srv/
```

I use a `docker-compose.override.yml` in my development environment to add ports on my local machine and it works well.

Now, I'd to set up circleci to:

1. Run the tests
2. Deploy to AWS

But I couldn't find any proper way to set up circleci config file to do that from my `docker-compose.yml` configuration.

It looks that extra steps are required.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?!